# Django REST Framework: handle exception for custom permission class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I built a custom permission class in Django that verifies the remote IP address of the request. If the request IP is one that's allowed, the `has_permission` class returns True, otherwise it returns False and the view responds with status code 403..

```py
class isVerifiedServer(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']

        return ip_addr == some_verified_ip
```

But I want the view to return 404 when this test fails, which is what the server responds with by default when a request is sent to a non-existent URL endpoint. I want to do this to make sure no one can figure out what a valid endpoint is.

DRF documentation says the following about changing the exception response of a custom permission class:

> Custom permissions will raise a `PermissionDenied` exception if the test fails. To change the error message associated with the exception, implement a `message` attribute directly on your custom permission. Otherwise the `default_detail` attribute from `PermissionDenied` will be used. Similarly, to change the code identifier associated with the exception, implement a `code` attribute directly on your custom permission - otherwise the `default_code` attribute from `PermissionDenied` will be used.

I've tried setting many attributes to achieve this, but the response is still always 403. This is what I've tried:

```py
class isVerifiedServer(permissions.BasePermission):
    code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
    status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
    default_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
    detail = 'Not Found'
    message = 'Not Found'
    default_message = 'Not Found'
    default_detail = 'Not Found'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']

        return ip_addr == some_verified_ip
```

What is the best way to achieve this?